# Regex to match everything between hash tags, multiline (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make a wiki markdown style parser where I have headers defined by hashtags. E.g:

```
# Heading 1

Some information here below the heading

Another paragraph of information

## Subheading 1

Paragraph related to the subheading
```

What I'm trying to do is capturing everything between one hash tag and another hashtag (as well as the hash tags themselves)

So in the above, I would want to capture

```
 Heading 1 (and #)

 Some information here below the heading

 Another paragraph of information
```

And...

```
 Subheading 1 (and ##)

 Paragraph related to the subheading
```

So far I have `/(#+) ?(.+)/` and that works perfectly for content on the same line after a hash tag, but not for any text separated by newlines.

However, I can't seem to match and newlines in the `(.+)` part of the regex pattern, without also gobbling up all of the new lines that start with hash tags.

I'm sure it's something simple.

Comment: In which language are you trying to implement this

Comment: PHP, edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this negation based regex:

```
# *([^#]+)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fO2eB2/2)

**Code:**

```
if ( preg_match_all('/# *([^#]+)/', $input, $matches) )
   print_r($matches[1]);
```